# ResizeGrip w/ DropShadow on Border

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use the ResizeGrip, but because I also require a DropShadow, this leaves it hanging out of the border people see, and makes it look weird. Is their any way to push it in?
http://speedcap.net/sharing/files/2c/5b/2c5b4e125f624f9f21f9f6b2fef85b50.png
I have a Window, then Grid, then Border with DropShadow, and then the Grid which contains my content.
http://pastebin.com/yTjNUXux